# Sorting an NSMutableArray of NSDIctionary objects on the basis of key value of dictionary that is a String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

I have an `NSMutablerray` of `NSDictionary` objects so that each item contains dictionary of various key value pairs. Each dictionary looks like this:

```
        id = 71324;
        type = UserQuestionExactMatch;
        url = "/user_questions/71324";
        value = "symptoms of hiv?";
        "verified_answers_count" = 2;
```

I have to populate a tableview with this array containing dictionary items as above on the basis of key value "type". So that if its '**type**' key value is '**UserQuestionExactMatch**' it comes at **first row**, if its '**AttributeRelationshipMatch**' it should come next and so on. Note that these types can be repeated i.e. there can be two dictionary objects of type '**UserQuestionExactMatch**' which should come **first**. How can I do this kind of sorting to implement a tableview? Is `NSSortDescriptor` useful in this case. If yes how can I implement it? Code snippets are welcome.

Comment: Have you read the spec for NSArray and NSMutableArray?  The answer is there.

Answer (score 3):

why not use NSArray's (NSArray *)sortedArrayUsingComparator:(NSComparator)cmptr

Since you the developer write the comparator block you can do anything you want.

Comment: I was typing the same thing when you posted this. See the example in [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingComparator:).

Comment: How can I compare two NSString values like UserQuestionExactMatch and AttributeRelationShipMatch for NSDictionary key 'type'?

Comment: @techsavvy - By reading the specs (if you're not savvy enough to have memorized them already).

Comment: Even basic questions should be answered, but you should at least do a google search.  I took your above question and googled it and found the answer.  Look at compare:, caseInsensitiveCompare: , localizedCompare: